# Cross-referencing without the prefix: "Figure, Eqaution...." for several references

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx

I am working with Lyx and the cross referencing works fine in general. But I wonder if there is a better way to do it in Lyx. When I refer to more than one e.g. equations, Lyx always past the prefix "Equation XY". I attached a screen shot.

Is there a way so suppress the prefix of the second reference? Without interfering with `hyperref`? So that at the end it looks like:

"....by Equation 3.22 and 3.23..."

This would look much better!! Same for figures and chapters and so on... anyone an idea?

[image]

[image]

I also tried to find a work around with `refstyle` package, as this is used by Lyx. But for any reasons I do not understand, this only works for `\ref` and not for any other kind of combination stated in the package manual. What am I doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

The function `\ref*{eq:dee1}` should basically do what I want. Additionally, I would need it without the brackets...

Comment: I don't know whether Lyx loads `amsmath` (or you load it), but that package provides the command `\eqref` that automatically formats the reference as "(nnn)", no preceding "Equation".

Comment: Mhh, but it does not do that? I loaded it (to be sure) in the preamble, but the result is the same (??). And is there a way to get rid of the brackets? I mean there must be a solution, as stating everytime: "Equation XY and Equation YX" can not be it. Or am I missing something?

Comment: If you get a result "(??)", that means the xref hasn't been resolved yet; the source file has to be processed twice for the xref values to be available.  If you have loaded `amsmath` and `\eqref` doesn't format the equation number as "(nnn)", then what Lyx has defined overrides the `amsmath` definition.  (As I said, I'm not familiar with how Lyx works, so I'm afraid I have no other suggestions.)

Comment: Yes seams like Lyx is doing something else here.... It is crazy, there must be a way to do it!? I googled like a maniac, but I could not find any solution to that!!

Comment: You might ask for help at the Lyx site: https://www.lyx.org/ .  Regarding plural references, their mail archive says, as of 2016, "not yet": https://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg103187.html

Comment: That the label is printed in the second line indicates that the starred form of `\ref` is not defined, which would make `\ref*{foo}` equivalent of `\ref{*}foo` I believe. If you activate `hyperref` with Document -> Settings -> PDF properties -> Use hyperref support, does that do anything?